# NextJS - public images won't work in dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, dynamic-routing

This is the look in normal pages,
[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRhMN.png)
[card's floating logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZYmH.png)

And this is what happens in dynamic routing,
[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIqHp.png)
[card's floating logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS5A1.png)

It works if I try adding forward slash before the image name, however, it will not work if I deploy my project to GitHub pages.

I want it to be works fine in both local and in live.

Answer (score 1):

Open the dev tools in your browser(normally `F12`), open the Network tab. and refresh page. you will find what happened to images you are looking for. Please provide more information. Or you can send a link to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js requires a forward slash when importing images from [the public directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets). So the accurate call would be:

```js
<Image src="/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
```

I assume you have not added your local images to your Git repository, as Git typically ignores images.

```
git add -f public/logo.png
```

Read more about git add [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).